# Microsoft Bot "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue"

Tags: botframework

I have created Microsoft Bot and hosted on azure with proper microsoft appid and password.

In Bot Channel, I have registred the hosted app service(bot).

My bot is working with emulator. but when i tried to work with other channel such as webchat, direct line, it is not working, it is showing error as "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue"

Please assist me to resolve the issue

Comment: Can you share the api endpoint and how you set up the webchat html/js?

Comment: When you say "created Microsoft Bot and hosted on azure with proper microsoft appid and password", do you mean you created it ON azure, or that you created it offline and published the code to Azure? Does this error happen you use 'test in webchat'? What does the developer console say?

Comment: Would you please install ngrok and tunnel your endpoint to localhost so you can debug what exception is your bot throwing? Let me know if you can do this or if you need further assistance